# storing data from input box in tkinter

Tags: python, list, button, tkinter

I got the assignment to build a program of a store.Now, the customers have to register to be able to buy, I made a main window that has buttons for each action I need to perform. When the user tries to register another window with the data needed to complete the registration appears. Now how do I store the data from the input-box into a list with a button?

Here's an example of how I'm setting each box that the user needs to fill:

```
var1 = StringVar()
var1.set("ID:")
label1 = Label(registerwindow,textvariable=var1,height = 2)
label1.grid(row=0,column=1)

ID=tkinter.StringVar()
box1=Entry(registerwindow,bd=4,textvariable=ID)
box.grid(row=0,column=2)

botonA= Button(registerwindow, text = "accept",command=get_data, width=5)
botonA.grid(row=6,column=2)
```

I tried setting the button to run a function that gets the input, but I't now working. Here's what I did

```
def get_data():
    print (box1.get())
```

Comment: Where is this `Button`? How is it not working - what happened, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry I did not add the code for the button in the question ,  it's just a normal button with the command being the get_data function

Comment: Have you tried changing `ID=tkinter.StringVar()` to `ID=StringVar()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems:

1. Unless you do `import tkinter` AND `from tkinter import *` - which you shouldn't; just choose one - your program will choke on either `var1 = StringVar()` or on `ID=tkinter.StringVar()`.
2. Define the `get_data()` function before binding it to a `Button`.
3. You assigned `box1` but then `grid`ded `box`.

The following sample will get the box's contents, add it to a `list`, and print the `list` to the console every time you click "Accept." Replace the names of parent windows, `grid` locations of each widget, and so on to suit your program.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.wm_title("Your program")

mylist = []

def get_data(l):
    l.append(box1.get())
    print(l)

var1 = StringVar()
var1.set("ID:")
label1 = Label(root,textvariable=var1,height = 2)
label1.grid(row=0,column=0)

ID=StringVar()
box1=Entry(root,bd=4,textvariable=ID)
box1.grid(row=0,column=1)

botonA= Button(root, text = "accept",command=lambda: get_data(mylist), width=5)
botonA.grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks that really printed the list I needed. Now I'll try to add it to the window I already have.. hope it works... and thanks again :D

Comment: ok so I've encountered a problem. I have the main UI with 3 buttons, I've set one button to open this up as another function, and when I press the accept button I'ts saying that the box1 variable is non existant. what could be the problem?

Comment: If `box1` and the button that calls it (`botonA` in this example, right?) are assigned in different functions, they will not be aware of each other. I attempted to illustrate this with `command=lambda: get_data(mylist)`: the reference `mylist` has to be passed as an argument to `get_data()`, or else that function won't be able to modify `mylist`. If I had defined `mylist` in its own function, nothing outside that function would even be able to access it at all. I recommend [reading about](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) object-oriented approaches to `tkinter`.

Comment: yeah I think that might be the issue.. the sad thing is that I can't post most of the code because most of my variables are in Spanish and changing them to english would take me like,years. Anyways, your help was very helpful in the end. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

to retrieve the value, you need to access the variable it is attached to, not the entry field on the screen:

```
def get_data():
    print (ID.get())
```

Comment: You can access the entry field as well.

Comment: Should I put the function before or after the window code?